# Orange for Data Mining and Unseen Test Sets

Tags: classification, data-mining, svm

I'm using Orange for Data Mining (http://orange.biolab.si/) 1 and LinearSVM in particular. Is there a way to save the learned model and use it with unseen test sets? I need to see the prediction results and to apply the model to new data.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is

```
import Orange, cPickle
from Orange.classification import svm

data = Orange.data.Table("2_new.tab")
classifier = svm.LinearSVMLearner(data, folds=10)
cPickle.dump(classifier, open("linear_svm.pck", "wb"))

# later:

classifier = cPickle.load(open('linear_svm.pck'))
data_validation = Orange.data.Table('show.tab')
print 'predictions:'
for e in data_validation:
    print e, "\t", classifier(e)
```